# Sharing string resources between platforms in PCL project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am creating Xamarin multi-platform mobile project where I want to use PCL shared project to share some parts of the code.

I also want to share one strings files between the platforms, as they will be the same for each of the platforms.

I've created new .resx file in my PCL project, but I dont know how can I use its values in my Android/iOS projects.
Any suggestions?

Content of AppResources.resx in PCL project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <resheader name="resmimetype">
        <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="version">
        <value>2.0</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <data name="ConnectButton" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Connect</value>
    </data>
    <data name="IpAddress" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>IP Address</value>
    </data>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just write:

```
var ipAddress = AppResources.IpAddress;
```

or

```
var connectButton = AppResources.ConnectButton;
```

You can find more information in the documentation: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/localization/

Comment: I am not using Xamarin Forms.

Comment: So? The documentation is still relevant.

Comment: I get: Common.AppResources is inaccessible due to its protection level error message.

Comment: @dease - Change the Custom Tool on your .resx file to be PublicResXFileCodeGenerator. You can change the Custom Tool by select Properties for the .resx file. Then make a small change to your .resx file to get the designer.cs file to regenerate. Then your resources should be public so you can access from another assembly.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I didn't realize you could make resources public. I learned something new. Thanks @MattWard.

Comment: @MattWard thanks a lot, it worked. Any idea how can I use translations strings in my layouts .axml files?

Comment: Not sure. I can only point you to the Xamarin doc - http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_5_-_application_localization_and_string_resources/